# How to remove row number by ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

There are some lines in a file like this

```
1 require 'socket'
2 require  'openssl'
.....
```

How to remove the row number

Comment: Only the number and not the space after it?

Comment: It is all ok. Only if they can fit the grammar rules.

Comment: This is a really simple thing to do; You really need to show what you've tried, and explain how it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with a file sample called "test.txt":

```
1 require 'socket'
2 require  'openssl'
```

And this code:

```
File.open('new_test.txt', 'w') do |fo|
  File.foreach('test.txt') do |li|
    fo.puts li[/^\d+\s(.+)/, 1]
  end
end
```

I get this when I run it:

```
require 'socket'
require  'openssl'
```

While it seems convenient to use `File.read` or `IO.read` to "slurp" input files, and process them as a big string, it's not scalable. In the real world, where we can get files in the multi-GB range, slurping files can take down systems.

Instead, use line-by-line IO, like provided by [`foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-c-foreach). It's amazingly fast, and super efficient, only reading a line at a time. In benchmarks I've done with giant files, it was easily within the ballpark with `read` as far as speed, but without the potential threat of consuming all RAM.

`li[/^\d+\s(.+)/, 1]` is a shorthand way of [applying a regex to a string](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), and extracting the part needed. `/^\d+\s(.+)/` is [a pattern](http://rubular.com/r/458IXbaFE4) that says "start at the beginning of the string, find digits followed by a space, then capture everything from there to the end of the line". Read more about Ruby's implementation of regular expressions in the [Regexp documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html).

Comment: Good answer, ttm.  A small detail re File.read/IO.read: some readers may infer that File and IO both have a read method.  Maybe add (IO#read), possibly with a link.  No need to reply as I'll delete this comment.  As I said, it's a very small point.  Also, liked your use of "slurp".

Comment: Well, File and IO both have `read`, since File inherits from IO. `File.methods.grep(/\bread\b/)`. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/File.html lacks a mention of `read` but `ri File::read` will show the docs for IO::read.

Comment: The reason I mentioned that was because when I first saw a mention of File.read I looked for it in the [File class at ruby-docs.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/File.html) and of course didn't find it. I had to poke around a bit to discover it was in the IO class.  Yes, I should have used `ri`.

Answer (score 2):

```
File.write(file_path, File.read(file_path).gsub(/^\d+/, ""))
```

Comment: Since it would be blanks at the head of the line so i change to `/\s*\d+/, ""`. But it dose not look like the origin file. Every line is too long, so the `#` would comment the contents that should not be

Comment: `sub(/^\d+/, '')` would be faster and more efficient than using `gsub`.

Answer (score 1):

Use regexp like this `^\d+\s`. Parse file line by line and replace line part suits regepx to empty string.